# Query single column and return comma separated Laravel PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
 $getStrain = DB::connection('mysql')->select('
    SELECT
        
       b.yeast_class_id
    FROM 
        yeast_classes AS a
    LEFT JOIN
        classes_per_yeast AS b 
    ON 
        a.id = b.yeast_class_id
    WHERE
        b.yeast_id = "'.$id.'"
    GROUP BY
        b.yeast_class_id
');

dd($getStrain);
```

and it returns something like this

[image]

But what I want to do is get a response something like this

`1,4,5,6,7`

where all `yeast_class_id` will be combined together

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From that array of objects you have you could `pluck` the field you want from them into an array:

```
Illuminate\Support\Arr::pluck($getStrain, 'yeast_class_id')
```

Or put the array into a Collection and use the `pluck` method on the Collection:

```
collect($getStrain)->pluck('yeast_class_id')->all()
```

If you want a comma separated string of the list:

```
collect($getStrain)->pluck('yeast_class_id')->join(',')
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Helpers - Array & Objects - `Arr::pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-pluck)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Helpers - Miscellaneous - `collect`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-collect)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `all`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-all)

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods - `join`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-join)

Answer (score 1):

Check the helper [values()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-values)

```
$getStrainValues = $getStrain->values();
```